# Derivations on $C(X)$ where $X=\{1,2,...,n\}$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

The linear map $\delta:C(X) \to C(X)$ (where $C(X)$ is the set of all continuous functions from $X\to \mathbb{C}$) is a derivation meaning that: $$\delta(fg) = \delta(f)g+f\delta(g)$$
The question asks for finding all derivations on $C(X)$ where $X = \{1,2,...,n\}$.
I wanted to start with $X=\{1,2\}$. But I have no idea how to do this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't we have any assumption that $\delta$ is linear?

Comment: @user159517 In the question I saw, there wasn't an assumption that $\delta$ is linear. But every where I see the definition, it says it's a linear map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $n=2$, $C(X)$ is a 2-dimensional vector space, generated by functions $f_1, f_2$ such that $f_i(j) = 1$ if $j=i$ and $0$ otherwise.

Since $\delta$ is linear, it suffices to find $\delta(f_1)$ and $\delta(f_2)$ to determine $\delta$ completely.

Now $f_i^2 = f_i$, therefore
$$\delta(f_i) = \delta(f_i^2) = 2\delta(f_i)f_i\,.$$
Therefore $\delta(f_i) \in C(X)f_i = \mathbb C f_i$. Let $k\in\mathbb C$ such that $\delta(f_i)=kf_i$. The above equations yields $kf_i = 2kf_i$.
thus $\delta(f_i)=0$, and since this holds for all $i$, it follows that $\delta = 0$.

The general case is not very different.

Comment: How did you find the generators of $C(X)$

Comment: A function $f$ on $X$ is completely determined by the value it takes on each point, i.e. $f(1), f(2), \dots, f(n)$, so $C(X)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb C^n$.

Comment: Is there a proof for this somewhere? Because I asked this question, too but it's closed. I don't know how to prove this.

Comment: You can try to prove it yourself. The isomorphism is $f\mapsto (f(1), \dots, f(n))$. Can you prove it's injective? Surjective?

Comment: Yes I've prove this. But where is the $f_i$?

Comment: $f_i$ is the preimage of an element of the canonical basis of $\mathbb C^n$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133502/discussion-between-lucy-and-astyx).

Comment: I don't see any differences between this case and the general case. Am I wrong? Because in the general case we also have $f_i^2=f_i$ and so on.

Comment: You are right, the general case is exactly the same, apart from the 2 first sentences.